# How to run python file in AWS S3 bucket from EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I tried run python file from AWS S3 storage like

```
python s3://test-bucket/test/py_s3_test.py
```

I'm getting Error :

```
python: can't open file 's3://test-bucket/test/py_s3_test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to run python file resides in AWS S3.

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to download it from S3 first. If you can use the `http` interface to S3, you could do something like `curl https://s3_url/ | python`.

Comment: As @jordanm pointed out, you can't directly stream an s3 file with python. On top of his answer, you can also try aws-cli for such operations !

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it will work.

```
aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket/path/to/file/hello.py - | python
```

**Explanation:** Its downloading the file from S3 and then passing stream to python for execution.

Alternatively, you could split it into multiple steps as well like download the file, save it to any local file and execute the locally saved file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Though I'm still `stretching` my head to understand, why you need to download the file stored in `S3` and execute? Are you looking for something like `AWS Lambda`?

Comment: yes, Work for me.
Created batch file to copy , execute and delete.